# Handle inheritance with Cubit

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-cubit

I have one common state where I need to handle multiple states like the Loading state and Error state.

All other states should have access to both states. So I can re-use these states to base screen and handle those states at single place.

Below is the common state

```
abstract class CommonState{}
class InitialState extends CommonState{
}

class UnauthorizedState extends CommonState{
}

class LoadingState extends CommonState{
  String? loadingMessage;
  LoadingState({this.loadingMessage});
}

class ErrorState extends CommonState{
  String? errorMessage;
  ErrorState({this.errorMessage});
}
```

I have added the cubit for the common state as below.

```
class CommonCubit<S extends CommonState> extends Cubit<S>{
  CommonCubit(S initialState) : super(initialState);
}
```

I want to use this common cubit and state it everywhere in the app. Can use LoadingState, and ErrorState everywhere. I have tried the below approach but it is not working.

Below is the Login screen state.

```
class LoginState extends CommonState {}

class UserAuthorized extends LoginState {}

class UserUnauthorized extends LoginState {}
```

Below is the cubit for the login screen

```
class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState>{
  LoginCubit() : super( InitialState() ) {
    checkUserAuthorized();
  }

  void checkUserAuthorized() {
    emit(UnauthorizedState());
  }
}
```

Here, I am getting an error that "The argument type **InitialState** can't be assigned to the parameter type **LoginState**. " So not getting how can I achieve this part. Can anyone please help me with this?

Please check above details.

Comment: i like to do the same. did you solve this?

Comment: I am checking a few alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

`class LoginCubit extends Cubit<LoginState>` means that `LoginCubit` can only emits `LoginState` itself and **subclasses** of `LoginState`.

`LoginState` is subclass of `CommonState` and `InitialState` is subclass of `CommonState` but they doesn't have any relationships with each other. You can imagine that they are both on same level of "inheritance tree".

To use `InitialState` in `LoginCubit` your `LoginCubit` should extend `Cubit<CommonState>` (or `CommonCubit<CommonState>`, seems like common cubit unused at all)

Hope that helps to resolve your issue. However I don't recommend to use common states at all. Please read docs of Flutter block and several articles regarding BLoC. Pretty sure after reading you will change your implementation.

Comment: I want a common mechanism for the loader and error handling. So I can get rid of adding the same code in multiple places.

Comment: I have tried your implementation but the issue that I am facing is from the CommonCubit, I can't pass any state apart from the CommonState. Like If I want to emit Loader cubit, I cannot do it.